# Make a django readonly field visible on the admin

Tags: python, django

I'm developing a Django project in which I want to allow users to edit a specific field only on add_view. So I've overridden the change_view method on the admin.py so it can set my readonly_fields there. However Django won't display readonly_fields.

It seems really wird for me that a readonly field is not displayed. I mean, if it's readonly, where is the part of it where it says read? It should be readable (only), and not ediable. If I wanted to hide it, there should be an option called hidden_fields or something. Don't you guys agree?

I wonder if is there any straighforward way of make readonly_fields visible on my admin, but not ediable.

### my admin.py looks like this:

from django.contrib import admin
from core.models import Box

```
class BoxAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        self.readonly_fields = ('colour',)
        return super(BoxAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id)

    def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        self.readonly_fields = []
        return super(BoxAdmin, self).add_view(request, extra_context=c)
```

Comment: Is not enough to add `readonly_fields = ('colour',)` tuple to your `BoxAdmin` class? From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields)

Comment: Are you sure it's not there? Unless you explicitly set `fields` or `fieldsets`, `readonly_fields` appear at the bottom, after all editable fields.

Comment: @Gocht, Well. It looks like I have to set the fields attribute on my model admin in order readonly_fields to work. That's really strange once it says on the docs that Django will use the fields set on the model as the default field set for ModelAdmin.fields' attribute.

Comment: Oh!! Indeed, they appear on the bottom. Sorry guys, my bad. I feel really stupid and dumb right now.

Comment: AAARGH. Cost me hours of my life. Anyway. Thanks. Is there a way to put the field up again?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting `self.readonly_fields`, you should override [`get_readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_readonly_fields).

```
def get_readonly_fields(request, obj=None):
    if obj is None:  # add form
        return []
    else:
        return ['colour']
```

Comment: I figured out the problem and it happens to be with my lack of attention. Actually Django does display readonly_fields but I couldn't see it because they are displayed on the bottom of the form when you don't set the ModelForm.fields attribute, which was pretty much my case. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The `ModelAdmin` object is instantiated once, so there's a risk that if changing `self.readonlu_fields` will affect other users browsing your site at the same time. So I recommend the approach above, even now that you've realised that your current code is displaying the fields at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: You are right! I've already noticed that and fixed. Actually my usecase consider user permissions. I created a permission called Box_full_access. So instead of set readonly_fields based on instance, I check on change_view() based on if user has box_full_access perm I set readonly_fields = [], else readonly_fields = ['color', 'field1', 'field2', ...].

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem and it happens to be with my lack of attention. Actually Django does display readonly_fields but I couldn't see it because they are displayed on the bottom of the form. When you don't set the ModelForm.fields attribute they go to the bottom, which was pretty much my case.